# OnClick not working on youtubeplayerview

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Currently working on application with integrating youtube player in it, all things working fine, the only problem I'm facing is that I'm not able to get onClick call back on youtubePlayerView. I'm trying to toast youtube video title when user click on youtube player. It's working fine when no video is loaded in youtube player but as soon as I initialised the youtubePlayerView and loadVideo clickListener start not working. How to handle clickListener in youtube player?

This is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:onClick="onClick"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/player">
    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubePlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@color/black"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/video_player_bottom_sheet"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My code for playing video :

```
@Override
protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return mYouTubePlayerView;
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    mYoutubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
    mYoutubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);

    if (!wasRestored) {
        mYoutubePlayer.loadVideo("0g0sy2x_vX4");
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),videoTitle,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far with some piece of code.

Comment: @VivekMishra Please see the code

Comment: try adding clicklistener via code or try changing your click method name.

Comment: I already tried mYoutubePlayerView.setOnClickListener but also not working

Comment: then put your click code on the relative layout. that player view will be having click event of it's own so it might not work .

Comment: Also tried that one but still no success. Everything working fine if youtubePlayerView in not intialized and video not loaded.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Override` from your method that you have defined for your method `onClick()` and add this to your player component in xml

```
android:clickable="true"
```